# Slick Slider: Go to slide with link and mark active links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I want to use a link to go to a certain slide inside a slick slider.

At the moment I'm using the following code for that (You can see it here: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/xxPRLKK):

```
<div class="slider slider-for">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <a href="#" data-slide="3">go to slide 3</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="4">go to slide 4</a>
    <a href="#" data-slide="5">go to slide 5</a>
  </div>
```

And this JS code:

```
 $('.slider').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
 });

 $('a[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
   $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
 });
```

It works fine to jump do a certain slide.
But I need to mark the current slide inside the navigation as active and add a class `.active` to the link.

Is that possible?

I know that there is a thing like slider syncing with `asNavFor`. But I can't use that in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an active class when clicking on those nav items.
You can see it here https://codepen.io/sifat009/pen/VwrmzPm

Here is the code i've changed.

```
 $('.slider').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   arrows: false,
   fade: true,
 });

 $('a[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
   $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
   $('a[data-slide]').removeClass('active');
   this.classList.add('active');
 });
```

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: I noticed, that the links don't get marked as active if I use the arrow keys from the slider. Is there a way to do that? Since that wasn't part of the initial question, I added a new one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71007114/slick-slider-mark-custom-nav-link-as-active-when-navigate-with-arrows

Comment: @Cray you can check my answer to your another post https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023245/5146848